# Convergence of an infinite sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Is it possible to use the comparison test for convergence in the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac 1 n$$

The exercise says that I should find a linear function $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(x)<\sin(x)$ if $0<x<\pi/2$ but I don't understand how that would help.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I´m sorry! I wrote it in the spanish way, I´ll change right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $g(x) = x/2$ satisfies $\sin(x) > g(x)$ for all $x < \pi/{2}$. Moreover, we have that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty g(1/n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}
$$

does not converge. What does this tell you?

Comment: I get the idea, I do, but there is only one thing I am not really comfortable with... That inequality is true only when $x<\pi/2$. Why I don´t need to know what happens when x is greater than that?

Comment: Ok, I got it while I was posting that. Thanks! One thing though, how can I prove $sin(x)<x/2$?

Comment: @LunaSage : Notice that $\sin x = x/2$ when $x=0$, and $(d/dx)\sin x = \cos x = 1$ when $x=0$.  But $(d/dx)(x/2) = 1/2 < 1$.  The cosine function decreases gradually, reaching $1/2$ when $x$ gets up to $\pi/6$.  That means $\sin x$ is increasing faster than $x/2$ until $x$ gets up to $\pi/6$.  And you really only need to know that $x/2<\sin x$ when $x$ is sufficiently small. That's because only finitely many terms in the series are bigger than any specified positive number, and changing only finitely many terms will not alter whether the series converges or not.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (otra idea): since $\;\sin\frac1n>0\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;$ , we can use the limit comparison test:

$$\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac1n\;\;\text{converges}\;\;\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\;\;\text{converges}$$

and since the rightmost one is the harmonic series....

Comment: Yes, it´s a much more elegant proof, but I´m not allowed to use that test in this case. It solves the problem, nevertheless, so... gracias!

Comment: @LunaSage, Dado que hablas del criterio de comparación, que usualmente se ve junto con el criterio de comparación *de límites* , me imaginé que sería más directo...Igual sabrás que puedes votar positivamente las demás preguntas si consideras que te ayudaron en algo, aunque sólo puedas *aceptar* una sola.

Answer (score 1):

We shall use the following:

**Fact.** *If $x\in [0,1]$, then $\sin x\ge ax$, where $a=\cos( 1)>0$.*

*Proof.* For every $x\in [0,1]$
$$
\cos 1\le \cos x,
$$
and integrating in $[0,x]$ we obtain
$$
\int_0^x cos (1)\,dt\le \int_0^x\cos t\,dt,
$$
and hence
$$
ax= \big(\cos( 1)\big)\,x\le \sin x. \tag*{$\Box$}
$$

Now, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, using the above Fact we ontin 
$$
\sin\frac{1}{n}\ge \frac{a}{n},
$$
and as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a}{n}$ diverges, so does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{1}{n}$, by virtue of the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin\frac 1 n \geq \frac{1}{2n},
$$
so by comparison, the series your're asking about diverges.

The linear function involved is $x\mapsto x/2$.  That function is ${}<\sin x$ if $x$ is positive and sufficiently small.